# I got this error "Operand should contain 1 column(s)" where am i wrong?

Tags: mysql, insert

I searched over other questions on the site. Other solutions that i found does'nt solve my problem. Any idea?

```
   INSERT INTO evraklar(evrak_tipi_grubu, evrak_tipi, evrak_konu, evrak_subeye_gelis_tarihi, evrak_gonderen, evrak_alici, evrak_tarihi, evrak_sayisi, evrak_aciklama, evrak_kurum_icindenmi, gelen_evrak_tarihi, gelen_evrak_sayi, gelen_evrak_etakip, evrak_kaydeden_ybs_kullanici_id,kaydeden_kullanici_birim_id)
     VALUES (
    (6,43,'Test amaçlı girilen  konu',STR_TO_DATE('12/12/2012', '%d/%m/%Y'),0,566,STR_TO_DATE('12/12/2012', '%d/%m/%Y'),'5555555555','YBS:110 nolu evrağa cevaben yazılan yazıdır. Alıcısı:Antalya Valiliği - İl Sağlık Müdürlüğü',0,STR_TO_DATE('12/12/2012', '%d/%m/%Y'),'5555555555',777777777,1,685),
    (6,43,'Test amaçlı girilen  konu',STR_TO_DATE('12/12/2012', '%d/%m/%Y'),0,612,STR_TO_DATE('12/12/2012', '%d/%m/%Y'),'5555555555','YBS:110 nolu evrağa cevaben yazılan yazıdır. Alıcısı:Mersin Valiliği - İl Sağlık Müdürlüğü',0,STR_TO_DATE('12/12/2012', '%d/%m/%Y'),'5555555555',777777777,1,685),
    (6,43,'Test amaçlı girilen  konu',STR_TO_DATE('12/12/2012', '%d/%m/%Y'),0,616,STR_TO_DATE('12/12/2012', '%d/%m/%Y'),'5555555555','YBS:110 nolu evrağa cevaben yazılan yazıdır. Alıcısı:Niğde Valiliği - İl Sağlık Müdürlüğü',0,STR_TO_DATE('12/12/2012', '%d/%m/%Y'),'5555555555',777777777,1,685),
    (6,43,'Test amaçlı girilen  konu',STR_TO_DATE('12/12/2012', '%d/%m/%Y'),0,616,STR_TO_DATE('12/12/2012', '%d/%m/%Y'),'5555555555','YBS:110 nolu evrağa cevaben yazılan yazıdır. Alıcısı:Niğde Valiliği - İl Sağlık Müdürlüğü',0,STR_TO_DATE('12/12/2012', '%d/%m/%Y'),'5555555555',777777777,1,685),
    (6,43,'Test amaçlı girilen  konu',STR_TO_DATE('12/12/2012', '%d/%m/%Y'),0,616,STR_TO_DATE('12/12/2012', '%d/%m/%Y'),'5555555555','YBS:110 nolu evrağa cevaben yazılan yazıdır. Alıcısı:Niğde Valiliği - İl Sağlık Müdürlüğü',0,STR_TO_DATE('12/12/2012', '%d/%m/%Y'),'5555555555',777777777,1,685)
    )
```

i am using mysql with php.

Comment: You could have narrowed this down: I'm sure this whole long query isn't necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: -1: Simple typo / not reading syntax in documentation

Comment: Urgent situation. Copy paste. You can easly understand the problem without long data insertion i think.

Comment: @caglaror: The "urgentness" of your situation is completely irrelevant, and it is also irrelevant that I can discover your problem by scanning through your huge query. This is not a helpdesk. We are not here to service you. SO is a Q&A repository and it is your responsibility to post concise, meaningful questions about programming languages that will help others in the future and do not include unnecessary fluff. You shall take the time to make this happen, regardless of your "urgentness". Thanks.

Comment: @NagarajS you funny :) , you copied my answer , and you tell him check your answer :) ? .

Comment: Nagaraj S and echi_Me saw my wrong.

Comment: Guys this is also not a chatroom.

Comment: @caglaror: Yes, and so did I, immediately, because it's obvious. You should have read the documentation. You're confusing "I can't answer this" for what I'm _really_ saying, which is that "SO is not what you think it is". Please take more care with your questions in future. Again, this is not a personal helpdesk and it is not a code debugging service.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit you are right. I am sorry and i will be carefull. I read the docs about error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to remove the `()` from values , or it will be considered as one entry .

try that:

```
   INSERT INTO evraklar(evrak_tipi_grubu, evrak_tipi, evrak_konu, evrak_subeye_gelis_tarihi, evrak_gonderen, evrak_alici, evrak_tarihi, evrak_sayisi, evrak_aciklama, evrak_kurum_icindenmi, gelen_evrak_tarihi, gelen_evrak_sayi, gelen_evrak_etakip, evrak_kaydeden_ybs_kullanici_id,kaydeden_kullanici_birim_id)
 VALUES 
(6,43,'Test amaçlı girilen  konu',STR_TO_DATE('12/12/2012', '%d/%m/%Y'),0,566,STR_TO_DATE('12/12/2012', '%d/%m/%Y'),'5555555555','YBS:110 nolu evrağa cevaben yazılan yazıdır. Alıcısı:Antalya Valiliği - İl Sağlık Müdürlüğü',0,STR_TO_DATE('12/12/2012', '%d/%m/%Y'),'5555555555',777777777,1,685),
(6,43,'Test amaçlı girilen  konu',STR_TO_DATE('12/12/2012', '%d/%m/%Y'),0,612,STR_TO_DATE('12/12/2012', '%d/%m/%Y'),'5555555555','YBS:110 nolu evrağa cevaben yazılan yazıdır. Alıcısı:Mersin Valiliği - İl Sağlık Müdürlüğü',0,STR_TO_DATE('12/12/2012', '%d/%m/%Y'),'5555555555',777777777,1,685),
(6,43,'Test amaçlı girilen  konu',STR_TO_DATE('12/12/2012', '%d/%m/%Y'),0,616,STR_TO_DATE('12/12/2012', '%d/%m/%Y'),'5555555555','YBS:110 nolu evrağa cevaben yazılan yazıdır. Alıcısı:Niğde Valiliği - İl Sağlık Müdürlüğü',0,STR_TO_DATE('12/12/2012', '%d/%m/%Y'),'5555555555',777777777,1,685),
(6,43,'Test amaçlı girilen  konu',STR_TO_DATE('12/12/2012', '%d/%m/%Y'),0,616,STR_TO_DATE('12/12/2012', '%d/%m/%Y'),'5555555555','YBS:110 nolu evrağa cevaben yazılan yazıdır. Alıcısı:Niğde Valiliği - İl Sağlık Müdürlüğü',0,STR_TO_DATE('12/12/2012', '%d/%m/%Y'),'5555555555',777777777,1,685),
(6,43,'Test amaçlı girilen  konu',STR_TO_DATE('12/12/2012', '%d/%m/%Y'),0,616,STR_TO_DATE('12/12/2012', '%d/%m/%Y'),'5555555555','YBS:110 nolu evrağa cevaben yazılan yazıdır. Alıcısı:Niğde Valiliği - İl Sağlık Müdürlüğü',0,STR_TO_DATE('12/12/2012', '%d/%m/%Y'),'5555555555',777777777,1,685)
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `()` near values

```
INSERT INTO evraklar(evrak_tipi_grubu, evrak_tipi, evrak_konu, evrak_subeye_gelis_tarihi, evrak_gonderen, evrak_alici, evrak_tarihi, evrak_sayisi, evrak_aciklama, evrak_kurum_icindenmi, gelen_evrak_tarihi, gelen_evrak_sayi, gelen_evrak_etakip, evrak_kaydeden_ybs_kullanici_id,kaydeden_kullanici_birim_id)
     VALUES 
    (6,43,'Test amaçlı girilen  konu',STR_TO_DATE('12/12/2012', '%d/%m/%Y'),0,566,STR_TO_DATE('12/12/2012', '%d/%m/%Y'),'5555555555','YBS:110 nolu evrağa cevaben yazılan yazıdır. Alıcısı:Antalya Valiliği - İl Sağlık Müdürlüğü',0,STR_TO_DATE('12/12/2012', '%d/%m/%Y'),'5555555555',777777777,1,685),
    (6,43,'Test amaçlı girilen  konu',STR_TO_DATE('12/12/2012', '%d/%m/%Y'),0,612,STR_TO_DATE('12/12/2012', '%d/%m/%Y'),'5555555555','YBS:110 nolu evrağa cevaben yazılan yazıdır. Alıcısı:Mersin Valiliği - İl Sağlık Müdürlüğü',0,STR_TO_DATE('12/12/2012', '%d/%m/%Y'),'5555555555',777777777,1,685),
    (6,43,'Test amaçlı girilen  konu',STR_TO_DATE('12/12/2012', '%d/%m/%Y'),0,616,STR_TO_DATE('12/12/2012', '%d/%m/%Y'),'5555555555','YBS:110 nolu evrağa cevaben yazılan yazıdır. Alıcısı:Niğde Valiliği - İl Sağlık Müdürlüğü',0,STR_TO_DATE('12/12/2012', '%d/%m/%Y'),'5555555555',777777777,1,685),
    (6,43,'Test amaçlı girilen  konu',STR_TO_DATE('12/12/2012', '%d/%m/%Y'),0,616,STR_TO_DATE('12/12/2012', '%d/%m/%Y'),'5555555555','YBS:110 nolu evrağa cevaben yazılan yazıdır. Alıcısı:Niğde Valiliği - İl Sağlık Müdürlüğü',0,STR_TO_DATE('12/12/2012', '%d/%m/%Y'),'5555555555',777777777,1,685),
    (6,43,'Test amaçlı girilen  konu',STR_TO_DATE('12/12/2012', '%d/%m/%Y'),0,616,STR_TO_DATE('12/12/2012', '%d/%m/%Y'),'5555555555','YBS:110 nolu evrağa cevaben yazılan yazıdır. Alıcısı:Niğde Valiliği - İl Sağlık Müdürlüğü',0,STR_TO_DATE('12/12/2012', '%d/%m/%Y'),'5555555555',777777777,1,685);
```